# Handling Large Amounts Of Folders In Linux, Best Structure For Efficiency

Tags: php, linux, filesystems

I have a PHP project that I am working on building for a client and I'm having to essentially convert their old system and data over to my "better" system. The problem I am having is with their old file structure for storing PDFs.

Currently, the folder system is configured by their First name, Last name in subfolders, with the last 4 of the social attached to the end for what I presume is to prevent duplication.

```
Files > A > B > Alan_Bob_1234
```

Because their system is extremely NON-compliant, I feel like I should change this but need advice on the structuring of the new file system on the Linux server.

My first thought was just to have one folder that contains the UNIQUE ID of every "Applicant".

```
Files > 0cowxuRoGj
```

The concern I have here is that fact I have 14,000+ applicants to transfer files for, and this number will continue to grow every day.

**My Question:**
Will having 14,000 + and growing folders within the Files folder increase processing time for the server so much that it will degrade response times for seeking? Is it more advisable to implement a sub-folder system like the original design to combat this issue?

Regardless I need to get the social out of the folder name. If I need to sub-folder these applicants, what might be the a good scheme for the sub-folder names as I don't want to be dependent on the first and last names remaining the same, because in their current system, updating the name causes the old files to be lost, and a new folder to be created.

Comment: What's wrong with their old structure? Having a large number of names in a single folder is slow, grouping them like this is a good way to prevent that.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for the point you made, I didn't consider that as an option as I've never used it. However, the only true problem with the current structure is that the last 4 of the social security number are being used and that if the user's names are changed, the old files become ghosts with nothing connected to them. I am looking for a better solution. Maybe the A > B structure with the UNIQUE ID within the sub folder?

Comment: If a user's name changes, you copy all their files over to the new name. But it would be better to come up with a permanent, unique username system. Regardless of how you name the users, you can use the `A > B` hierarchical structure. You could use the first two letters of the username, rather than the first name and last name.

Comment: @Barmar, That's a reasonable idea. So you think that way I have described above with having that many folders will surly create speed issues yes?

Comment: Some of these strategies were designed years ago, when Unix filesystems had simpler designs. It's possible that modern designs handle huge directories better, so you could put everything in one directory. You'll need to benchmark it.

Comment: We need to know, if files are related to a person/user. And do they have their metadata saved in any kind of database, that you know. Is there a record in DB that says, that Alan Bob has a file of ID 1234?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of files per directory depends on the filesystem used, how was the filesystem created, version of the kernel and probably some other things. If you're using ext4 with a recent kernel, millions of files per directory shouldn't pose a problem. But to be on the safe and more portable side, splitting the huge list is recommended.

If your "UNIQUE ID" is not a serial, but a random with good distribution, the easy solution is:

```
Files > 0 > cowxuRoGj
```

This should split your list of files among 62 directories, which allows you to store hundreds of thousands of files on any filesystem you might encounter in your lifetime.